# Как отправить куки в spa?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

Есть такой код, по сути обычная авторизация. Когда я отправляю логин и пароль - все ок, сессия сохраняется на сервере, но как сохранить информацию на клиенте, что бы можно было авторизовываться? Нужно как-то с сервера передать куки? Если да то как

```
const auth = (request,response,next)=>{
  console.log(request.isAuthenticated())
    if(request.isAuthenticated()){
        next()
    }else{
        response.json(false);
    }
};

passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
  models.user.findOne({ where: { id: id } })
    .then((users) => {
      users = (users.id === id) ? users : false;
      done(null, users);
    })
});

passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'login'},function(login, password, done) {
    models.db.user.findOne({ where: { login: login } })
      .then((user) => {
        if(!user) {
          return done(null,false, { message: 'Неверный логин' });
        } else if(login === user.login){
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result) {
            if(!result) {
              return done(null,false, { message: 'Неверный пароль' });
            } else {
              return done(null, user);
            }
          });
        }
      })
    })
);

router.post('/authcheck', cors(), auth, (request, response) => {
  response.json(true)
});

router.post('/signin', cors(), (request,response,next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
        if (err) { 
            return next(err); 
        }
        if (!user) { 
            return response.json(false); 
        }
        request.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { 
                return next(err); 
            }
        response.cookie('token', '12345ABCDE');
            return response.json(true);
        });
    })(request, response, next);
});
```